# How do I use PixelReader's getPixels() method?

Tags: java, javafx

How do I convert a javafx.scene.image.Image to a byte array in the format bgra?

I tried doing:

```
PixelReader pixelReader = img.getPixelReader();
int width = (int)img.getWidth();
int height = (int)img.getHeight();
byte[] buffer = new byte[width * height * 4];
pixelReader.getPixels(
        0,
        0,
        width,
        height,
        PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(),
        buffer,
        0,
        width
);
```

but it didn't work, my byte[] array buffer is still filled with zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scanlineStride i. e. width must be multiplied by 4, i. e.

```
PixelReader pixelReader = img.getPixelReader();
int width = (int)img.getWidth();
int height = (int)img.getHeight();
byte[] buffer = new byte[width * height * 4];
pixelReader.getPixels(
        0,
        0,
        width,
        height,
        PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(),
        buffer,
        0,
        width * 4
);
```

Comment: Good catch, but that wasn't the problem, heh. Anyways, I fixed it and thanks for your input.

Comment: Any chance that you could share how you fixed it?